# Creating attractive borders for DIV

Tags: css

I found beautiful div borders here:

[Demo for nice div border](http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/demo)

PLease enter cursor in box. You will see beautiful blue shaded border for div.

How such a nice border can be created? any other reference?

Comment: It's bootstrap, also, use firebug for these purposes, as your question doesn't suit for Stackoverflow, as you are asking for your fav offsite resource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this:

```
input
{
    border-radius: .2em;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;

    -webkit-transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    -moz-transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    -o-transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
}

input:focus
{
    border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
    outline: 0;
    outline: thin dotted \9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px     rgba(82,168,236,.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
}
```

Basically what is used for the border is a box-shadow on focus. Also they create a transition between the box-shadow for a fade-in effect.

*Remeber that you can inspect every element in your browser, thus can view the css code of the element*

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6yXd/)**

---

[More info about box-shadow](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/).

Comment: +1 for including working demo at jsFiddle

Comment: @nkmol: thanks. I have edited as my need http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/r6yXd/1/ but when I test it in my actual  applcation testing on chrome. IT shows different color. Not what I can see in fiddle. Browser issue?

Comment: No this is no browser issue. I'm also using chrome and tested it on my local server. Updated your fiddle for some adjustments: http://jsfiddle.net/r6yXd/2/. Only the input with name "url" shows the focus box-shadow effect now.

Answer (score 1):

That's `box-shadow` in CSS3:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

---

FYI, if you're using browser like Chrome, you can right click on the element, and select "inspect element" to see the style applied to it.

Comment: you are showing box-shadow demo to whom who does not know about outline